# egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, discord

I'm trying to install a Discord bot on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.

However, I keep getting egg_info failed. There's plenty of threads on this, I know that. I've tried every "solution" I've found in those threads and none of them seems to solve my error.

Anyone able to assist me further? I'll attach a pic of the log and the error.

Log file: `egg_info failed`https://pastebin.com/AQGPP4UX

Comment: I've inlined your images, but you should add the relevant parts of the code and logs as text anyway.

Comment: Here's the pip.log, hope that'll do. Seriously can't figure this one out..

https://pastebin.com/AQGPP4UX

Answer (score 1):

According to your error log, It seems, You tried to install a package that needs some python headers, actually, when you try to install an application with GCC, you need header files and header files in Python are in `python-dev` package in `Debian/Ubuntu/...` and in `python-devel` package in `Redhat\CentOS\...`

You must install `python-dev` and `setuptools` on your system:

Python 2:

```
 apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

Python 3:

```
 apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

Comment: totte@panel:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
[sudo] password for totte: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version.
python3-dev set to manually installed.
python3-setuptools is already the newest version.
python3-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
totte@panel:~$  

Edit: This was very hard to read, I'm trying to figure out how to make a codeblock :P

Comment: @Totte Are you used `sudo` to install package? `sudo pip install what_you_want`